# Puppeteer installation has error

Tags: google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

I have problem with puppeteer. I cannot install it on my debian 8.7.1.
These are the steps:

1.install chrome:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

2.install nodejs & puppeteer:

```
apt-get install curl
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
npm i puppeteer
```

When I run `npm i puppeteer`, the errors are:

```
> puppeteer@0.11.0 install /root/node_modules/puppeteer
> node install.js

ERROR: Failed to download Chromium r499413! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
Error: Download failed: server returned code 403. URL:  https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Linux_x64/499413 /chrome-linux.zip
at ClientRequest.https.get.response (/root/node_modules/puppeteer/utils/ChromiumDownloader.js:195:21)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:316:30)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:7)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:565:21)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:116:23)
at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:454:20)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:7)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:266:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! puppeteer@0.11.0 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@0.11.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely   additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-10-04T12_32_37_607Z-debug.log
```

I run the command `npm config set PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true` to  skip download but it wants to download chromium yet.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: So Chromium download failed? What if you try to install it separately?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I try to install it sepratly. Now it has anoter error:`(node:2156) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: spawn EACCES
(node:2156) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

Comment: OK, that is fine! That means that some of your puppeteer function calls failed. Try to remove some of them/choose the right selectors and see if it works.

Answer (score 8):

Try below options;

```
1) npm config set puppeteer_skip_chromium_download true
2) Add puppeteer_skip_chromium_download=true to .npmrc file where the package.json location
```

After that run `sudo npm install --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`

References;

```
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2270
https://medium.com/forcit/seo-for-single-page-applications-8543619e1d0c
```

Comment: This does work, as long as you don't want the browser zip file. If you do want the browser  file then this will pass npm install and fail during npm test since there is no browser file to use.

Answer (score 6):

upgrade your puppeteer version (optional)

```
npm set strict-ssl false

npm config set puppeteer_skip_chromium_download true
```

and  `npm install` again.

Answer (score 3):

This line of code works fine for me

```
npm install --ignore-scripts puppeteer
```

Comment: But now I get this error when I run the script: Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 116.0.5845.96). This can occur if either

Answer (score 2):

try
sudo npm install puppeteer --unsafe-perm=true

Answer (score 1):

> Error: spawn EACCES

This roughly means that puppeteer cannot execute Chrome due to permissions issues. If you're having troubles I have a [docker image here](https://github.com/joelgriffith/browserless) that you can use and interact with remotely. The issue with Chrome and many linux distros is that installation is quite a challenge to solve.

Answer (score 1):

If you have chrome already you can use system variable to skip installation

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#environment-variables

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue when I was using Puppeteer.
I see two parts to your problem, 
 1. The inability to download Chromium and getting `403 error` other is 
 2. `Error: spawn EACCES` problem

**I'll start with `Error: spawn EACCES` problem as it's more subtle and tricky**

This is because your debian machine doesn't have the required dependencies installed in order to run Puppeteer. These dependencies differ between distributions(CentOS, Ubuntu/Debian etc...).

Follow these steps,

1. Install all the dependencies required. You can refer this link for the list, https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-unix
2. After all the dependencies are installed, install npm and configure proxy in .npmrc if you are behind a VPC/proxy.
3. Then, as usual, go ahead with `npm i puppeteer` and proceed as always

**Next to address your inability to download Chromium problem.**

Are you behind a proxy? That was my issue.

I noticed on executing `npm i puppeteer` the script downloads Chromium from an external URL which from your log is https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Linux_x64/499413/chrome-linux.zip

`npm` is unable to download from this external URL because of the proxy blocking it.
The way I solved this issue was by configuring `.npmrc` file with the proxy settings

```
npm config set proxy http://<proxy_username>:<proxy_passowrd>@<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>

npm config set https-proxy http://<proxy_username>:<proxy_passowrd>@<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>
```

Note:

1. If your username/password contains any special characters you need to URL encode them. Eg. If your username is `bruce\wayne` then you need to URL encode it as `bruce%5Cwayne` where %5C="\"
2. If your proxy has no authentication then ignore  and

Examples:

```
npm config set proxy http://bruce%5Cwayne:darkknight@11.434.2.23:8080

npm config set https-proxy http://bruce%5Cwayne:darkknight@11.434.2.23:8080
```

So, try configuring your `.npmrc` file using the commands given above and then try running `npm i puppeteer`. The proxy will no longer be blocking the external URL and you would be able to download Chromium.

Let me know if this works and reach out to me if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue. The best work around for this is to create a project using npm init, then install puppeteer using command "npm install puppeteer --save". This way chromium also gets installed with out any issues.Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Please set the following in `.npmrc`
puppeteer_download_host = https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors

or

`npm config set puppeteer_download_host  https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors`